# File Yaml to object using Yamlbeans library

Tags: file, class, object, yaml

I tried using yaml file named contact to write it into object. Unfortunately it didn't work...

```
    package javaapplication22;

import com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlException;
import com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class JavaApplication22 {

    public class Contact {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, YamlException {

    YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader("contact.yml"));
    Contact contact = reader.read(Contact.class);
    System.out.println(contact.age);

}

}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.Could somebody help me?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a real question.  Tell us the behavior you want, the behavior you're actually getting, and the exact wording of any error messages that you are receiving.

Comment: Can you show us the content of your file 'contact.yml' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't reference JavaApplication22$Contact in a static-method.**

---

In one word, in order to call

```
Contact contact = reader.read(Contact.class);
```

You have to make sure you can call the constructor there:

```
Contact test = new Contact();
```

**In your code, you can't new an object of class Contact in main method.**

---

There are two methods to work around:

1) change Contact to static

```
public static class Contact {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

2) Don't define Contact as an inner class

Comment: Thank you!!! But, where is my mistake? Why  has it to be like that ? Any explanation?

Comment: @user6056445 I edit the answer, hope it  can help you.